# Want a green check mark to appear to the right of a text field onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a very basic html form with a series of text fields. I am simply looking for a way to have a green check appear to the right of the field if some value has been entered. I tried some CSS (don't know much about it) to no avail. Any ideas? I've been looking for quite awhile. here is what I have so far. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>CRM Application Form</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            label.valid {
                width: 24px;
                height: 24px;
                background: url(assets/img/valid.png) center center no-repeat;
                display: inline-block;
                text-indent: -9999px;
            }

            label.error {
                font-weight: bold;
                color: red;
                padding: 2px 8px;
                margin-top: 2px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>  

            <h1 style="text-align:center">CRM Application Form</h1>
            <form>
                <fieldset style="background-color:lightgray">
                    <legend style="font-weight:600">Personal Information</legend>
                    Date of Birth:
                    <input type="date" id="DOB" name="DOB" required><br>
                    Social Security #:
                    <input type="text" id="SS#" name="SS#" value="" onchange="checkField(this.value)"><br>                    
                    Location:
                    <input type="text" id="Location" name="Location" /><br>
                    Ethnicity:
                    <input type="text" id="Ethnicity" name="Ethnicity" /><br />
                    Citizenship:
                    <input type="radio" id="Yes" name="Yes" value="Yes" />Yes
                    <input type="radio" id="No" name="No" value="No" />No<br />
                    Gender:
                    <input type="text" id="Gender" name="Gender" /><br />
                    Marital Status:
                    <input type="text" id="Marital Status" name="Marital Status" /><br />
                    Previous Last Name:
                    <input type="text" id="PLN" name="PLN" /><br />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset style="background-color:lightgray">
                    <legend style="font-weight:600">Contact Information</legend>
                    Address:
                    <input type="text" id="Address" name="Address" required><br />
                    Email:
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset style="background-color:lightgray">
                    <legend style="font-weight:600">Education</legend>
                    Education History:
                    <input type="text" id="EH" name="EH" /><br />
                    Academic Level:
                    <input type="text" id="AL" name="AL" /><br />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset style="background-color:lightgray">
                    <legend style="font-weight:600">Other Information</legend>
                    Military Status:
                    <input type="text" id="MS" name="MS" /><br />
                    POI:
                    <input type="text" id="POI" name="POI" /><br>
                    Employment Goal:
                    <input type="text" id="EG" name="EG" /><br />
                    Program:
                    <input type="text" id="Program" name="Program" /><br />
                    Market Segment:
                    <input type="text" id="Mkt" name="Mkt" /><br />
                    FA:
                    <input type="checkbox" id="FA" name="FA" />
                    Payment:
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Payment" name="Payment" /><br />
                    Notes:<br />
                    <textarea id="Notes" name="Notes"> </textarea><br />
                </fieldset>
                <input type="submit" />

            </form>

</body>

    </html>
```

Comment: SO is not a "write my code for me" site. If you have a specific problem, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: @Scimonster he did not ask for someone to write the code for him- although I'm guessing he would like that.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Yes, because there is no existing JS that attempts to do that.

Comment: @Scimonster then I would suggest you redirect him there and tell him to search more thoroughly next time.

Comment: How about go learn CSS and JS :D

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to the inputs you're trying to listen to - and put your green check mark image to the right of it, but with a style='display:none;'

```
<input type='text' id='tbTest1' class='CheckChange'/>
<img src='CheckMark.jpg' style='display:none;'/>
```

Then add some javascript to show the image when a value is present - and to hide it if not:

```
$("#document").ready(function(){
    $(".CheckChange input[type='text']").on("change", function(){
        if ($(this).val().length > 0)
            $(this).next("img").show();
        else
            $(this).next("img").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea for inserting the image dynamically.  In the example, I used a `div`, but you can substitute the element that you need.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').change(function() {
    var $input = $(this),
      $flag = $input.next();

    if (!$input.val()) {
      $flag.remove();
    }
    
    if ($flag.length == 0 || !$flag.is('.valid')) {
      $input.after('<div class="valid"></div>');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.valid {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Thanks Talmid. I ended up using the JQuery toggle() function. That helped.